# SparkSQL error: collect_set() cannot have map type data

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

For SparkSQL on hive, when I used `named_struct` in the query, it returns results:

```
SELECT id, collect_set(emp_info) as employee_info
FROM
    (
     SELECT t.id, named_struct("name", t.emp_name, "dept", t.emp_dept) AS emp_info
     FROM mytable t
    ) a
GROUP BY id
```

But when I replaced `named_struct` with `map`, I get an error:

```
SELECT id, collect_set(emp_info) as employee_info
FROM
    (
     SELECT t.id, map("name", t.emp_name, "dept", t.emp_dept) AS emp_info
     FROM mytable t
    ) a
GROUP BY id

ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'collect_set(a.`emp_info`)' due to data type mismatch: collect_set() cannot have map type data; line 36 pos 27;
'Distinct
```

I wish to return a map of `name` and `dept`, how to use with `collect_set`?
FYI: This query with `map` runs without issues in Hive(Hue)

Comment: can you try  using collect_list and see if it works?

Comment: @Aaron: Thanks, collect_list works. Any idea how to dedup the resulting array[map()]?

Comment: can you post an example of what you are trying to dedup ? ideally you will have to deal with Scala Mutable classes to do distinct.  which I would not recommend.  normally maps can contain duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the map to json first using `to_json()` method, then you can collect the set in same query such as:

```
SELECT id, collect_set(to_json(map("name", emp_name, "dept", emp_dept))) AS emp_info
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id
```